# Regexp with arrays and elements (Js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, integer, element

Language is JS

Suppose we have an array full of positive and negative integers in a string with other letters (e.g. 1a or -2d), the question is how can you call all the strings that starts or contain positive integers using regexs? 
I'm new to regexs and from what I've learned I tried to use /^[0-9]/.tes...... , but It didn't work, so, any other solutions that you think might work ?

Comment: Add your trial code

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: If it's too advanced for you, use a duller knife to skin that cat. arr.filter(function(i) { return parseInt(i) > 0; })

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function positiveElements(arr) {

    //write your RegEx
    let reEx = new RegExp(/^\d+\w*$/);

    //return the filtered array
    return arr.reduce((p,c) => {
        //push the element only if it passes the RegEx test!
        if(reEx.test(c)) p.push(c);
        return p;
    }, []);
}

//sample test
let arr = ["1a", "-3d", "4k", "-7e", "-100f", "24c", "1945y"]
positiveElements(arr);

//Output
// ["1a", "4k", "24c", "1945y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since positive numbers are numbers that are greater than 0. We can check that the string starts with a number, and it's not 0.

Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). For every string, test if it starts with a number between 1-9, since integers won't start with a 0.

```js
const getPositives = (arr) => 
  // the string should start with a number between 1 to 9
  arr.filter((s) => /^[1-9]/.test(s));

const arr = ["1a", "-3d", "4k", "-7e", "-100f", "24c", "1945y"]
const result = getPositives(arr);

console.log(result);
```

If your string does have numbers that start with 0s, we change the pattern to:

```js
const getPositives = (arr) =>
  // the string can start with a sequence of 0s, but afterwards there should be a number between 1 to 9
  arr.filter((s) => /^0*[1-9]/.test(s));

const arr = ["1a", "-3d", "4k", "-7e", "-100f", "24c", "1945y"]
const result = getPositives(arr);

console.log(result);
```